# Autmapper Call method on every property map

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper, automapper-9

I want to call a specific method xyz() on every property mapped by generic mapper configuration. Is this possible?

I am using Automapper v 9. Purpose is to call the method on each property mapped by Automapper to check add remove data at runtime.

```
public static IMapper CreateMapper<TSource, TDestination>()
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(
                cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.Advanced.AllowAdditiveTypeMapCreation = true;
                    cfg.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;
                    cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
                    cfg.CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>()
                    .PreserveReferences()
                });

            config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

            return config.CreateMapper();
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't _sound_ like a good idea. Perhaps you can explain in greater detail what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: You can use beforeMap that will definitely match with your requirement

Comment: Is aftermap a good workaround because it will use reflection and it is not very optimal solution. I don't have sound knowledge on reflection performance but if I have to search for a property using reflection then I don't need to call for separate method I can easily map using source and destination.

Comment: Sorry for late response @LucianBargaoanu. Actually I have defined a generic mapper for multiple classes with inner child collection using ICollection interface. I have create a new question for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60212096/automapper-not-mapping-mapping-properties.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of-course you can do it upon your need I mean before map or after map globally !
Use this official [Auto-mapper Doc.](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html) for reference

Comment: .afterMap call only after completion of mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call what you want. I already use like this.

```
  CreateMap<UserMessage, USER>()                    
                .ForMember(dest => dest.X, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.A!= null ? MessageExtensions.GetCvTitle(src.A) : string.Empty))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Y, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => MessageExtensions.GetFacultyName(src.B)))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Z, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => MessageExtensions.GetDepartmentName(src.C)))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.T, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => MessageExtensions.GetProgramName(src.D)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need it for generic configuration as you can see it in my source code snapshot. ForMember is not useful in generic case.